# Notation for product of three sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If I have *3* sets

$x = \{a,b,c\}$

$y = \{1,2,3\}$

$z = \{i,j,k\}$

What is the proper notation for the product of all of these sets such that? i.e.

$\{(a,1),(a,2)......(c,3,k)\}$

Note that {a} is not selected here

$x \times y \times z $ would be wrong as this will give only triplets in this case.

Apologies for the lack of terminology.

Comment: Are you refering to cartesian product of those sets? If so why do you say $x×y×z$ is wrong?

Comment: Hi I think its wrong because the cartesian product would exclude combination like (a,1) from the new set. Ideally its the intercept of  x X y , x X Z, y X z and x X y X z...sorry for the confusion

Comment: I guess by the 'intercept' you mean the union of those sets

Comment: Why do you think such a product is interresting? If nobody finds them interresting it's quite unlikely that the construct will get a special name...

Comment: Sorry yes I meant union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly the set you want would be 
$$(x×y) \cup (x×z) \cup (y×z) \cup (x×y×z)$$
There is not a special notation for that

Comment: Thanks . .is there any notation for n sets?

Comment: @kPow989 What does that mean?

Comment: Hi Chase apologies for my basic questions. In my example I have three sets x,y,z. I was wondering was there general notation for doing this with and number of sets